# Beacons and Probe Requests in Residential WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I was just wondering if a Residential WiFi access point and router (utilising WPA2 security) could be configured to be able to utilise **passive** (beacon) and **active** (probe) methods (to allow discovery of the WiFi SSID) at the same time?

Is it the case that there can only be one or the other or **can both operate at the same time?**

Also, what is the relative effect on **bandwidth** (due to management overhead) when comparing the active and passive approaches?

Thanks in advance for any information on this.

Comment: You can do that if you flash your router with DD-WRT firmware. Scaning networks around while surfing internet! http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/files/site_survey_142.jpg

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of oversimplifying, it’s clients that scan to find APs, not the other way around. APs don’t really have any say in how clients scan. APs must transmit beacons at regular intervals as well as respond to probe requests with probe responses, so APs always do support both active and passive scans at the same time.

How a client scans is a client implementation detail that most vendors don’t bother to document. Many clients do “hybrid” scans where channels that can be scanned actively are scanned actively, and “DFS” channels (where you can’t transmit until you’re sure no nearby radar installation is using it) are scanned passively until the client sees a transmission on the channel, which would indicate that it is okay to transmit on that channel, in which case the client upgrades to an active scan on that channel.

Passive scanning has no effect on bandwidth, as beacons must already be sent at regular intervals for non-scan-related reasons. Active scanning is one small probe request per channel, and one small probe response per in-range AP, which is nothing. Even if an ill-behaved client were scanning all channels once per second, it works out to only about one tenth of one percent of the airtime on each channel.

Comment: Hi Spiff. Thanks for the response on this. Much appreciated. Just one further question: will clients continue to send out probe requests even when connected to an SSID (or is this again related to the actual software the client is using, so some will and some may not)?

Comment: @Goshy Clients scan the most when trying to find a network to join at boot or wake from sleep. Clients also scan some when they're getting poor signal strength from the AP they're on; they look for other APs to roam to. Even a client that is happily connected to a nearby AP may periodically scan in order to do Wi-Fi-based geolocation. If you leave some kind of Wi-Fi scanner app or widget running your your system, it might keep scanning all the time. Use an 802.11 monitor mode packet sniffer to see what a given client is actually doing.